# Recycler View automatically scrolls to inner recycler view on first load

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a root vertical recycler view and items are

1. ViewPager
2. Horizontal Recycler View
3. Horizontal Recycler View ...

When the data is first loaded, when entry animation stops, the root recycler view is slightly scrolled and 2nd item(the recycler view) is completely visible.

Why is this happening? And how to avoid this automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemsInserted`, it triggers a `requestLayout` in the `RecyclerView`.

After the layout, `RecyclerView` tries to `recoverFocusFromState`. And when it finds the first focusable child, it tries to bring it completely into view. If that focusable child is partially visible by the end of layout, it will cause a scroll and the focusable child will be fully visible.

In the above case, the child `RecyclerView` is the `focusable` child. The same can happen with `ProgressBar` or any other `focusable` view

### Solution 1

If you know your child views are not focusable. You can add

```
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your root `RecyclerView`

### Solution 2

Add `focusable="false"` to your non focusable childs

Answer (score 2):

use the solution posted at this issue https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/issues/224
here is the code snippet which worked for me

```
recyclerview.getAdapter().registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if(positionStart == 0) {
            (recyclerview.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(positionStart,0)
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these;

1. add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your parent layout or recyclerview
2. add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your parent layout or recyclerview
3. Not a good solution but maybe for now you can try: `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)`