# Android - Screen scrolls automatically to RecyclerView when loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am working on an Android (Java) app. I have a fragment with a top paragraph and below that a `RecyclerView`. When I launch the application and the screen loads, the contents are scrolled so that the top paragraph is completely out of the screen and the `RecyclerView` is the only thing visible.

As per this solution: [Recycler View automatically scrolls to inner recycler view on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860552/recycler-view-automatically-scrolls-to-inner-recycler-view-on-first-load) I tried adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and

```
focusable="false"
```

to the Recycler View but none of them worked.

This is the XML for the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/intro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a welcome text"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonOptions">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/pathsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix so that the page does not automatically scroll?

Comment: Its likely because of the scrollview thats wrapping around the recyclerview. I have seen similar issues with android when one scrollable view wraps another scrollable view. Have you tried removing the scrollview?

Comment: You want something like this: https://youtu.be/nUnPoxo_ZG4?

Answer (score 2):

You're adding `android:descendantFocusability` to the `RecyclerView`, although you need to disable the focus-ability from the child of the `ScrollView` because this automatic scrolling is caused by the `ScrollView`, not the `RecyclerView`.

So, to fix this you need to transfer the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from the `RecyclerView` to the direct child of the `ScrollView` which is the `LinearLayout`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        ....
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TextView
           ...
```